# JSON stringify works when previewing from Dreamweaver but not from .AIR file when application created

Tags: javascript, html, json, air, dreamweaver

I've been developing a simple application using Adobe AIR, the HTML and javascript version.

The application submits a form to an online URL.

The values of the forms are JSON strings.

I'm using this function to submit the data:

```
function fetchStudents()
{

    var stmt = new air.SQLStatement();
        stmt.sqlConnection = conn;
        stmt.text = "SELECT * FROM studentsTable2 WHERE deleted='0'";
        stmt.addEventListener(air.SQLEvent.RESULT, function(event){ 

            var result = event.target.getResult();
            sync_students = JSON.stringify(result.data);

            fetchCourses(); 
        });
        stmt.addEventListener(air.SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, errorHandler);
        stmt.execute();
}
```

`JSON.stringify` works when I test the application in DREAMWEAVER by using: preview in ADOBE AIR.

`sync_students` is then a JSON string filled with all the data from the table correctly formatted.

But when I have created the AIR file and installed the application and run it, it no longer works.

`sync_students` is then a JSON string but it is completely empty... `[{},{},{}]`

I have read around a lot and seen suggestions to use JSON2.js etc and I have tried these but I haven't been successful.

This is driving me crazy, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I thought I should follow up here cos I never did. The problem turned out to be the parser I was using. Changing the parser resolved the issue. It was so long ago I don't remember how or why anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the accepted answer of this question. The problem here was that garbage collection reclaims some var 'too soon' : in other words, the scope is baaad. :

[AIR Sqlite: SQLEvent.RESULT not firing, but statement IS executing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330971/air-sqlite-sqlevent-result-not-firing-but-statemet-is-executing-properly)

EDIT : All this is a question of scope. You should look into 'javascript scope' and 'javascript closure' keywords to have a better understanding of this (if i may suggest).

below just a (very) short summary about *ONE WAY* to define a 'class' in javascript :

```
var MyNameSpace = {};  
var MyNameSpace.SchoolDataSource = function() {
  this.publicMember = 2;
  this.publicFunction = function(x) {
        var newValue = this.publicMember + _privateMemberOne + x;   
        return _privateFunctionMul2(newValue); 
     } ;
  var _privateMemberOne = 1;
  var _privateFunctionMul2 = function (y) { return 2*y; } ;
};

var mySchoolDataSource = new MyNameSpace.SchoolDataSource();

mySchoolDataSource.publicFunction(3); // ok. (returns (3+2+1) * 2 = 12)
var bar = mySchoolDataSource.publicMember; // ok. ( === 2)
mySchoolDataSource._privateFunctionMul2(4); does not work, which is what we want.
var foo= mySchoolDataSource._privateMemberOne; // does not work, which is what we want.
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks so much for your answer, that might well be the issue and I'll look into it. Could you tell me if this could still be the problem if data.result does have a value?

If I alert result.data or result.data[0].fname I get values, if I alert sync_students straight afterwards I don't...